# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError c

Tags: java, class, dynamic, loading

I've written a program that loads classes via an inputstream.

This is the part where it loads the classes:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    byte[] bytes = ClassByteLoader.getClassByteMap().get(name);
    if (bytes != null) {
        System.out.println(name);
        return bytesToClass(name, bytes);
    } else {
        return ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(name);
    }
}
```

When I start the program with this method:

```
public static void loadClient() {
    try {
        Class mainClass = ByteClassLoader.getInstance().loadClass(getMainClass());
        Method mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        String[] params = new String[]{"-secureBoot"}; 
        mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) params); 
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then I get the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
It cannot find this class us/coop/client/g.

But the findClass method tells me that it is already loaded, because it printed out this:

us.coop.client.f

us.coop.client.ad

us.coop.client.g

My classloader class:

```
    public class ByteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private static final ByteClassLoader INSTANCE = new ByteClassLoader();

    public static ByteClassLoader getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private ByteClassLoader() {

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return findClass(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] bytes = ClassByteLoader.getClassByteMap().get(name);
        if (bytes != null) {
            System.out.println(name);
            return bytesToClass(name, bytes);
        } else {
            return ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(name);
        }
    }

    private Class<?> bytesToClass(String name, byte[] bytes) {
        if (super.findLoadedClass(name) != null)
            return findLoadedClass(name);
        return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length, getDomain());
    }

    private ProtectionDomain getDomain() {
        CodeSource code = new CodeSource(null, (Certificate[]) null);
        return new ProtectionDomain(code, getPermissions());
    }

    private Permissions getPermissions() {
        Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
        permissions.add(new AllPermission());
        return permissions;
    }

}
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What does your class loader do that's an improvement over the built in class loader?

Comment: @MarkW Oops, any idea on how I would achieve that?

Comment: @Takendarkk My naming sucks :s ClassByteLoader  loads the bytes from each class and stores it in a map. And ByteClassLoader converts the bytes into classes.

Comment: I think I had this all wrong here, are you attempting to launch some other (for the sake of argument) executable jar by invoking the main method?

Comment: @MarkW Yes, but I do not want the jar on the file system only in the memory.

Comment: @MarkW The jar file is encrypted and stored on the web.
I want it to make it harder to reverse engineer.
But is it possible want I want to achieve?

Comment: Check ur manifest and see if it is importing the package that contains us.coop.client.g class

Comment: @user3253880 Maybe this is the wrong way to go about it. Ive never tried it, but perhaps you could construct a ProcessBuilder, and a Process, to execute the java command against the remote URL, instead of attempting to get these classes into your JVM, or somthing similar? It doesnt sound like a pretty solution, but my mind sorta recoils when thinking about trying to add classes to my class path which only exist in memory.... Or maybe just good old obfuscation

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is unfortunately a "garbage" exception that has numerous possible causes.  But basically, it says that the ClassLoader found and loaded what purported to be the correct .class file but at some point in loading/verifying process something went wrong.  *Sometimes* if you look at the exception stack you will see an earlier exception that "provoked" the NCDFE, other times there's not a clue.  The best in your case would probably be to get it down to the simplest possible case, get that working, and then add back in stuff til it breaks again.